# call a soap webservice from ionic

Tags: angularjs, soap, ionic-framework

i'm trying to call a soap webservice using this method : http://mcgivery.com/soap-web-services-angular-ionic/ however my screen only shows a blank page instead of the login screen. what could be the probleim?

here's my services.js code:

```
.factory('loginService', ['$soap', function($soap){
var base_url = 'http://localhost/UserService3/WebService1.asmx';

return {
    GetUser: function(uname){
        return $soap.post(base_url,"getUserbyUsername", {Username: uname});
    }
};
}])
```

and here's my controller.js code:

```
 .controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$state', 'sharedProperties2','ConnectivityMonitor', '$ionicLoading', 'loginService', 
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, $state, sharedProperties2, 
ConnectivityMonitor, $ionicLoading, loginService) {

 $scope.show = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner>',
      showBackdrop: false
    });
  };

$scope.hide = function(){
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  };

$scope.userdata = {}

$scope.enterlogin = function(usern,pass)
{
     userFactory.GetUser(usern).then(function(response) {
            alert('get = ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
}
}])
```

Comment: Anything return in response.data?

Comment: @PareshGami theres no response. i'm thinking i might have missed out on something.

Comment: Can you put your example in plunkr or somewhere with live soap web service so i can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently it could not see the previous location of the added scripts angular.soap.js and soapclient.js, so i put the 2 files inside a folder named angular-soap inside the lib folder.